# warnings in The SharePoint Health Analyzer

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I have some warnings in The SharePoint Health Analyser.

I have seek high and low but on Google. Some solutions suggest to ignore the warnings. Other come with some solutions based on Visual Studio and PowerShell.

Is these warnings critical or should it be ignored

> Web Analytics: Monitors the health of the Data Analyzer Light
>   component.   Severity 2 - Warning   Category Performance   Explanation
>   The running time for the Data Analyzer Light component should always
>   be less than the threshold.
>
> Failing Services WebAnalyticsService (WebAnalyticsService)
>
> Web Analytics: Monitors the health of the Report Consolidator
>   component.   Severity 2 - Warning   Category Performance   Explanation
>   The running time for the Report Consolidator component should always
>   be less than 12 hours.
>
> Failing Services WebAnalyticsService (WebAnalyticsService)
>
> Accounts used by application pools or service identities are in the
>   local machine Administrators group.   Severity 2 - Warning   Category
>   Security   Explanation Using highly-privileged accounts as application
>   pool or as service identities poses a security risk to the farm, and
>   could allow malicious code to execute.  The following services are
>   currently running as accounts in the machine Administrators group:
>   SharePoint - 80 (Application Pool)  OSearch14(Windows Service)
>
> Failing Services SPTimerService (SPTimerV4)
>
> Title Drives are at risk of running out of free space.   Severity 2 -
>   Warning   Category Availability   Explanation Available drive space is
>   less than five times the value of physical memory. This is dangerous
>   because it does not provide enough room for a full memory dump with
>   continued operation. It also could cause problems with the Virtual
>   Memory swap file:  (WINSERVER2008R2 - C:).  Remedy Examine the
>   failing servers and delete old logs or free space on the drives. For
>   more information about this rule, see
>   "http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=142688".  Failing Servers
>   WINSERVER2008R2    Failing Services SPTimerService (SPTimerV4)
>
> Title Drives are at risk of running out of free space.   Severity 2 -
>   Warning   Category Availability   Explanation Available drive space is
>   less than five times the value of physical memory. This is dangerous
>   because it does not provide enough room for a full memory dump with
>   continued operation. It also could cause problems with the Virtual
>   Memory swap file:  (xxxxxxxxxx- C:).  Remedy Examine the failing
>   servers and delete old logs or free space on the drives. For more
>   information about this rule, see
>   "http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=142688".  Failing Servers
>   WINSERVER2008R2    Failing Services SPTimerService (SPTimerV4)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1)for web analytics, you need to add another database  as processing time increase with single db.

[Web Analytics: Monitors the health of the Data Analyzer Light component (SharePoint Server 2010)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh564133%28v=office.14%29.aspx)

2) For Web analyics reports, follow this link to fix it.
[Web Analytics: Monitors the health of the Report Consolidator component (SharePoint Foundation 2010)](http://technet.microsoft.com/library/ff805075.aspx)

3) For the App Pool account, If the error reporting the Farm Admin Account then ignore this rule. But if other than farm admin's account is mentioned then you should make sure why that account into local admin on the server. good practices always avoid local admin rights other than Farm admin account.

4 & 5) easy to ignore. no body having that much space.

Comment: for 1) the link I followed says 1. / Verify that the user account that is performing this procedure is a member of the Farm Administrators group / but I don't have groups, I have Active Directory Users.

Comment: For some Unknown reasons 2) is disappeared in SharePoint Health Analyzer.

Comment: 3) removed SP_ServiceApps user from administrators. How it come in administrators, I don't know. Not me
Anyway fixed

Comment: All this mess started after I have updated OWA. Lessons learned / never ever update your development server unless
it is a security thread

Comment: Thank you Waqas 
Your advice fix the warnings